# How can I suppress the addition of a blank new line after the class declaration in IntelliJ? (Code Style)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm having the problem that IntelliJ Idea keeps adding a blank new line after the class statement. A class like the one below

```
public class A {
   private String name;
}
```

gets formatted into this one below.

```
public class A {

   private String name;
}
```

The following diff show the blank new line between the class statement and the first field declaration.

[image: Diff]

My code style settings on *Wrapping and Braces* tab are as follows:

[image: Setting 1/3]
[image: Setting 2/3]
[image: Setting 3/3]

I was not able to find a setting that suppresses this additional new line. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: The setting is Editor/General/Ensure line feed at file end on Save

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In settings:  Editor|Code Style|Java on the 'Blank Lines' tab you probably have 'After class header' set to 1.  Change this value to 0 and the unwanted blank line won't be added by the formatter.